# android studio gradle define a local variable

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i want to create inside in my gradle.build file a local variable, because i have two different productFlavors with two differet path for jnlibs.
Then i use this gloabl variable to set this different path, for example for use in within the section dependies.

I want to do this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    def pathLibs;

    productFlavors {

        project1 {
            applicationId "com.test.project1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode=76
            versionName="5.2.6"
            pathLibs 'src/project1/jniLibs'
        }

        project2 {
            applicationId "com.test.project2"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode=66
            versionName="5.2.2"
            pathLibs 'src/project2/jniLibs'
        }
    }

}


dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'



        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSBasePlayer.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/assets.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/DxDrmDlc.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSBasePlayer.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSDataSource.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSEngine.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSHDMICheck.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSPlayer.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSStreamingDownloader.jar')
        compile files(pathLibs+ '/voOSUtils.jar')


}
```

you can create the variable "pathLibs" as in the example described above?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like what you really want to know is "How to use different dependencies for each product flavor". Maybe you can also describe what you actually want to achieve with this, because your whole approach seems strange and there is may be a different way to solve this.

Comment: If is possibile to have different dependencies for each product flavor then it is a solution, but i'm not find this solution.

Answer (score 2):

To define a global variable you can use something like this:

```
project.ext.set("pathLibs", value)
```

To access it from anywhere in the project:

```
project.pathLibs
```

Using `def pathLibs;` it becomes a local variable.

You can find more info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

Comment: I want to use this variable within the 'dependecies' section (in the build.gradle file), but I can not do it. But I can not do that, even following the code written by you (which I also found I)

Comment: How are you using the variable?

Comment: watch the variable 'pathLibs' describe in the example

Comment: I was wrong to write global, it is more correct to write local (I've changed the title)